# Is there any limit for number of azure file shares can be mounted to a AKS node?

Tags: azure-aks

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/operator-best-practices-storage#size-the-nodes-for-storage-needs) document, there is a limit to the number of azure disks that can be attached to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) node depending on the virtual machine type. Is there any such limit for azure file share mounts per node?

Answer (score 0):

AKS provides two primary types of secure storage for volumes backed by Azure Disks or Azure Files. Both use the default Azure Storage Service Encryption (SSE) that encrypts data at rest. Disks cannot be encrypted using Azure Disk Encryption at the AKS node level. With Azure Files shares, there is no limit as to how many can be mounted on a node.